# SSRS Matrix Dynamic Rows and Columns -- How to Compare one cell with another

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I have a problem which I hope someone can help me with

Assuming this is the data set

Year  Month Amount

2009  01    500

2010  01    300

2011  01    400

2008  01    400

I would like a grid to show:

```
   2008     2009       2010       2011
```

01     400      higher     lower      same

I've used the Matrix (tablix) capability to produce a grid

```
   2008     2009       2010       2011
```

01     400      500        300        400

but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

thanks,